# "be one hundred percent on board" what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> My mother wasn’t one hundred percent *on board*.

Is this a proverb?

The full text is:

> “Yes, we did argue that night, but it was nothing serious. Just a bit
>   of tension, wedding jitters, you know? She was finding it stressful.”
>   “She was finding what stressful, exactly?” “The wedding preparations.
>   Dealing with my family. They can be a bit . . . difficult.
>   Intimidating.” “Your family wasn’t happy about the wedding?” “I
>   wouldn’t say that, exactly.” He looks away. “My mother wasn’t one
>   hundred percent on board, but I loved Dana. And she knew I was going
>   to marry her.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are **[on board](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-board)** in the figurative sense, it means that you are willing to participate or that you find some plan agreeable.

> We're going to the movies Saturday night. Are you on board?

That is, do you want to come along?

> We wanted to rearrange our desks but our office manager was not on board.

That is, our office manager did not like the idea (and nixed the plan).

Comment: +1 for concentrating on "on board." In fact I hadn't understood the meaning of "on board."

Comment: @Peace - they fail to mention it, but “on board” is also an idiomatic expression, often used figuratively. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+board

Comment: On board in the OP's example is a nearly dead metaphor: you are either on board a ship or not. You cannot be less than 100% on board unless you are not on board at all. The problem with nearly dead metaphors, a stylistic problem, is that some readers will still envisage a ship with the mother not quite on board (climbing up a rope ladder?).

Comment: I imagine you could be 50% on board, one leg still on the gangplank. But I would say **not fully on board**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20fully%20on%20board%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 2):

**One hundred percent** is indeed used to mean "fully" or "completely".

It's listed in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-one-hundred-percent) with examples related to agreement and health:

> *I agree with you one hundred percent.*
>
> *I'm better than I was last week but I'm still not (feeling) a hundred percent.*
>   (= I'm not completely well).

It's also often used to describe strong effort and full dedication:

> She is dependable and consistent; she gives [one hundred percent](https://www.albionpleiad.com/2016/10/shuk-is-moving-up-and-digging-deep/) to pick up every ball, and leads well by example on the court.